# c# : How ot create a grid row array programatically

Tags: c#, .net, silverlight, grid, silverlight-5.0

I am working in c# and i am under a situation where i have a  grid (childGrid) and inside this grid i want to create 3 more grids dynamically.

I want to achieve it using arrays. My try to do this is:

```
Grid[] row = new Grid[counts]; //counts=3 in my case but decde dynamically.
for (int i = 0; i < counts; i++)
{
    row[i].RowDefinitions.Add(new RowDefinition());
}
```

I do so because i have one childGrid (parent grid) on that i will have 3 containers (3 more grid as container as child of chidGrid) so it is `row[i]` in my case (`for i :0 to <3`) (if you see the code). and on `row[0]`. i have a checkbox and two different UIelements at `row[1 & 2]` . I take different containers because if i select the check of `row[0]`(checkbox) it will set the opacity of `row[1].opacity=0.5;` and on unchecking it will do `row[2].opacity=0.5;`. So thats why i have different 3 grids container on a grid.

the line  `row[i].RowDefinitions.Add(new RowDefinition());` gives warning.

```
The object reference is not set to an instance of an object.
```

How to achieve this  ? **I can not do statically because i dont know statically the value of counts(which i assumed 3 here)**

Comment: What is the purpose of `RowDefinitions[counts]`?

Comment: The purpose to add the row is in the first row[0] i will display a check box if i select the check of thsi checkbox then i will set the opacity of row[2].opacity=0.5 and if i uncheck the checkbox at row[0] then i will set the opacity of row[2].opacity=0.5

Comment: I don't think you understand what you are writing. `RowDefinitions[counts]` gets the `counts+1`th element of the array, which is a `RowDefinition` and not a collection.

Comment: @AndrewArnold Ok, I have told you what i am trying to achieve using this. So is what i am trying to achiev can be done  just by doing this : row[i].RowDefinitions[counts] = new RowDefinition(); ? What do you think ?

Comment: You probably want something like `row[i].RowDefinitions.Add(new RowDefinition)`.

Comment: Ok let me implement this if i works.

Comment: Don't work :                    Grid[] rowgrid = new Grid[size];
                    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
                    {                          
                        rowgrid[i].RowDefinitions.Add(new RowDefinition());
                    }

Comment: What didn't work? Are you adding any `Grid`s to the `rowgrid` array first?

Comment: No, I am not adding anything before My code is this:                 Grid[] rowgr = new Grid[size];
                    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
                    {                          
                        rowgr[i].RowDefinitions.Add(new RowDefinition());
                    }

Comment: and exception obtained is: the object reference is not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: Hang on. Why are you using sub-grids at all? Why can't you simply add the three controls (`txtblkLabel`, `sp`, and `txtblkShowStatus`) directly to `childGrid`? You shouldn't need loops or arrays at all for this.

Comment: I do so because i have one childGrid (parent grid) on that i will have  3 containers (3 more grid as container as child of chidGrid)so it is  row[i] in my case (for i :0 to <3) (if you see the code). and on row[0]. i have a checkbox and two different UIelements at row[1 & 2] . I take different containers because if i select the check of row[0](checkbox) it wil set the opacity of row[1].opacity=0.5; and on unchecking it will do row[2].opacity=0.5;. So thats why i have different 3 grids on a grid.

Comment: All of those grids are so different though, using loops doesn't help anything. Just add them one by one.

Comment: @AndrewArnold please see the edit of question (i removed confusing part) you still haven't understood the question. I can not do it one by one because i dont know what will be the size of counts.It will be decided dynamically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't actually create any grids before you tried to add rows to them.

```
Grid[] row = new Grid[counts];
for (int i = 0; i < counts; i++)
{
    row[i] = new Grid();
    row[i].RowDefinitions.Add(new RowDefinition());
}
```

Comment: Thats it :) Now if i try to create opacity on different wiull it work  using this code ?

Comment: and one more question does this dont create 4 grid (if counts =4) : Grid[] row = new Grid[counts]; ? ( i thought it do)

Comment: Yes, it will create as many grids as you tell it to. Just make sure any objects are actually instantiated before you try to access or change their properties.

Comment: I still have a problem I dont know why i have all the UIelements in column 1. Even i dont this :           Grid.SetColumn(txtblkLabel, 0);
            row[0].Children.Add(txtblkLabel);
            Grid.SetColumn(sp, 1);
            row[0].Children.Add(sp); 
            Grid.SetColumn(txtblkShowStatus, 2);
            row[0].Children.Add(txtblkShowStatus);
            childGrid.Children.Add(row[0]);

Comment: You should probably post that in a new question.

Answer (score 1):

If I interpret your question correctly, the proper way to set all the rows to a default value is not to add them, but to set them.

```
for (int i = 0; i < counts; i++)
{
    row[i].RowDefinitions[counts] = new RowDefinition();
}
```

Comment: The purpose to add the row is in the first row[0] i will display a check box if i select the check of thsi checkbox then i will set the opacity of row[2].opacity=0.5 and if i uncheck the checkbox at row[0] then i will set the opacity of row[2].opacity=0.5

Comment: sorry dont work. The object reference is not set to an instance of an object.